# Mapping vertical values to Horizontal rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
I have two tables. First is ItemDetails and second is ItemHeaders.

ItemHeaders:
ItemID ItemName
1      Apple
2      Orange
3      Grapes

ItemDetails:
ID ItemHeader1 ItemHeader2 ItemHeader3
1  1           2           1
2  3           2           1
3  2           1           2
4  2           3           3

OutPut:  
ID   Categroy1   Categroy2  Category3
1    Apple       Orange     Apple
2    Grapes      Orange     Apple      
3    Orange      Apple      Orange
4    Orange      Grapes     Grapes

My Query:    
Select ID, i1.ItemName as Categroy1, i2.ItemName as Categroy2, i3.ItemName as Categroy3
From ItemDetails d
Left Join  ItemHeaders i1 on d.ItemHeader1 = i1.ItemID
Left Join  ItemHeaders i2 on d.ItemHeader2 = i2.ItemID
Left Join  ItemHeaders i3 on d.ItemHeader3 = i3.ItemID
```

Question: This is sample data and I have 50,000 records in ItemDetails. When I run my query it takes lots of time. Can someone suggest optimize query or best option to achieve above result? Please let me know if question or query is not clear.

**Edit:** There is an index on ItemID. You said about Pivot. How can I use pivot to get my result? And also there are 10 headers instead of 3. Here I have mentioned only 3.

Comment: Have you got indexe on `ItemID` field ?

Comment: is 3 the maximum number of headers?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from index.hope left join is correct.i mean in your requirement you cannot use inner join .

what is the purpose of ItemDetails ?
you can have one column called itemHeader and type .

why you will need to run 50000 and above rows at one go.why not use paging ?

you can pivot the thing in front end also .